# Alignment, Constraint struggle with Labels

Tags: swift, xcode, alignment, constraints

So I am very struggling with those constraints... I just can't make it.

Here is the view with 9 Objects within:

[image: Image of my view]

[image: Image of my view with borders]

[image: Overview of all objects]

If someone is fast at this, I think the best option is to just send you my project. 
I already tried collection view etc. but NO CHANCE :(

Greetings!

Comment: What is the problem you need to be fixed it's not mentioned in the question?

Comment: 1) it doesn't get smaller in size when I want to make the displayView smaller. 2) It gets me many warnings and doesn't adapt its aligments as it should do.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to set minimum font size and set labels width and height as equal to each other. Did you do this?